# Syntax Error : '{'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am writing a C program that uses an array of integers which is a part of a structure. The structure is:

```
struct test
{
    int *ques;
    int a;
    int b;
    int len; // len is the length of the array defined in the structure as ques.

};
```

In a function after this declaration I have assigned a value to the len as:

```
cases[0].len=5; // here cases is an array of the type struct test.
```

and then I have used `malloc` to allocate memory to the array member `ques` as follows:

```
cases[0].ques=(int *)malloc(cases[counter].len*sizeof(int));
```

After that I have tried to fill in the array `ques` as follows:

```
cases[0].ques[5]={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3};
```

and while compiling I get an error at the above line stating that:

```
maxmin.c(47) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: `cases[0].ques[5]={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3};` -- Where did you get the idea that that is valid C? Even if it were, it would be trying to cram 5 values into ques[5] ... when only ques[0] ... ques[4] were allocated.

Comment: @JimBalter : I will say size of `ques` is `cases[counter].len` which may or may not be `5`.

Comment: As always: do not cast the pointer, returned by `malloc`.

Comment: @MadHatter Eh? The OP wrote `cases[0].len=5;`, so it's 5. (And "size of" should refer to the size in bytes, i.e., `sizeof`)

Comment: @JimBalter:  What I meant was `cases[0].ques=(int *)malloc(cases[counter].len*sizeof(int));` `counter` is not known and hence space allocated to `ques`. Anyways, I think it should be `0` in this case, so you were right the first time.

Comment: @MadHatter Ah, ok ... presumably OP meant `cases[counter].ques=(int *)malloc(cases[counter].len*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 4):

This is invalid: `cases[0].ques[5]={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3};`

You can initialize an array in C this way, only at the time of declaration of array.

To fill in the values at this point in your C program you should use `for` loop to fill every index separately.

Right now the C compiler parses this statement as:

Value of index `5` of array `ques` at index `0` of structure array `cases` of type `struct test` is `{-7,-6,-5,-4,-3}`, which is certainly invalid since you cannot use `{` while assigning  a value to a variable.

**Update at OP's comment:**

You can keep all the values in temp array say `int temp[50] = {...};` then after allocating space to `ques` you can use `memcpy` function to copy `len` number of values to `ques`.

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there a way to initialize an array which has many integers, say about 50? I have to give the values statically so i dont think i can use a for loop.

Comment: @user3153983 MadHatter's update mentions `memcpy`, which is the most sensible answer. If you find this answer helpful, you should accept it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have C99 or C11, you can use a compound literal in conjunction with `memcpy()` or `memmove()` to initialize the new array:

```
memmove(&cases[0].ques, (int []){-7,-6,-5,-4,-3}, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

This also fixes the problem that you allocate `cases[0].ques` as a pointer to 5 integers, but you then try to assign to a single element that is beyond the end of the allocated array.  The code is also inconsistent in that most of it references `cases[0]` but the `malloc()` call references `cases[count]` in the argument list.  Not automatically wrong, but definitely unusual.

The array literal can be as big as you need.  The only tricky bit is the size argument (third argument) to `memmove()`.  I ducked fast on that; repeating the compound literal doesn't feel like the right move, but manually counting isn't a good solution either.

Well, you could if `memmove()` wasn't a macro that objected to being given 7 arguments instead of 3 (GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2)!

```
(memmove)(&cases[0].ques, (int []){-7,-6,-5,-4,-3}, 5 * sizeof(int));
memmove(&cases[0].ques, ((int []){-7,-6,-5,-4,-3}), 5 * sizeof(int));
```

The first invokes the function `memmove()`, not a macro. The second creates a single argument by wrapping parentheses around the compound literal.  Both compile.

Note that although the compound literal looks like a cast and a brace-initializer, I'm not sure it is strictly a cast — it is best not to think of it as a cast but as a compound literal.

Incidentally, if the objective is to add N random values to an array of N integers (as mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980389/syntax-error/22980949?noredirect=1#comment35093267_22980454) to one of the other answers), then you won't want to use this technique — the integers in the example are implausible as a random sequence.  If you do want 50 random numbers in some range, you'll use a random number generator (possibly [`rand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rand.html), possibly
[`lrand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lrand48.html), possibly something else) to create the values in an appropriate range, using a simple `for` loop to initialize the correct number of array elements.

Comment: Nice way to utilize typecast and `memmove` (`memcpy`). ++my_knowledge, hence ++Vote.  :-)

Comment: "I'm not sure it is strictly a cast" -- it's not, since `{...}` isn't an expression.

Answer (score 3):

assign value to each array element as,

```
cases[0].ques[0]=-7
cases[0].ques[1]=-6
...
cases[0].ques[5]=-3
```

since you are assigning the value after declaration. C allows {} use for initializing array at the time of declaration. not after that.

Comment: Thank you sir/madam. Is there a way to initialize an array which has many integers, say about 50? I have to give the values statically so i dont think i can use a for loop. and the method mentioned above seems tedious.

Comment: @user3153983 how you get those 50 values? any logic?

Comment: @user3153983 ok. how do you get those 50 values? from user input or how you get those values?

Comment: Dear all, my array has to have values that are totally random. This is to test a program. So i guess i have to assign each individual element in the array.

Comment: @user3153983 you can add the code to get the random number inside a loop and assign each number as you get to cases[0].ques[i]. isnt it possible to use this technique for your program?

Answer (score 1):

`ques[5]` is an `int`, you cannot assign an array to it

Also, C doesn't allow to assignment to multiple elements in an array like that. You can only do it at **initialization**. So create a new array and initialize with those 5 elements and copy it to your destination with `memcpy()` or `memmove()`

```
int[] tmp = {-7,-6,-5,-4,-3};
memcpy(cases[0].ques, tmp, 5*sizeof(int));
```

Alternatively you can assign values to `ques[i]` separately

Answer (score 1):

I hope you realize why `cases[0].ques[5]` is wrong.

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

The above code works because you are doing the initialization of array at the declaration time.

If you have

```
int arr[5];
arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // THIS WONT WORK
```

Here, you'll have to use for loop and fill each index.

also, when you do

```
int arr[5];
arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

In the above code, what you are trying to do is, put some value in arr[5]. That is just one index of the entire array.

Additionally, as the comment suggests, `arr[5]` is the 6th element in the array of size 5. Now although it won't give error, but be prepared to get some unexpected results. :)

Comment: `arr[5]` is one index that isn't even part of the array; it is one element beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Ohh yeah, forgot to mention that. I had that in mind, halfway through the answer. Adding it to the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
cases[0].ques[5]={-7,-6,-5,-4,-3};
```

You cannot do this, this initializer only valid when you define an array.

You should do something like:

```
for (start = -7, i = 0; i < cases[0].len; i++, start++) {
    cases[0].ques[i] = start;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you meant to increment `start` from -7 to -6.
So use `++start` instead of `start--` or `--start`

Comment: @gargankit Oops, fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of time I do not program in C, but I think the only situation in which you can do a complete array declaration is in the time that you declare it:

```
int a[] = {...}
```

But not this way:

```
int a[5];
a = {...};
```

Also, in your case, you are doing

```
int a[5] = {...}
```

and this means that you are trying to assign an array to an integer.

Also, it's better if you do [not do a cast in the malloc call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc):

```
cases[0].ques = malloc(cases[counter].len * sizeof(int));
```